# How is e-value calculated in BLAST 2 sequences (BLAST+)?

Tags: bioinformatics, blast

In the BLAST+ packages, you can align two sequences instead of searching a database:

`tblastn -query seq1.fa -subject seq1.fa`

The web BLAST documentation states that e-values are calculated from the nr database:

> Because BLAST 2 Sequences uses the **size of the current nucleotide or protein nr database to calculate Expect values**, you may need to significantly increase the Expect threshold in order to see shorter alignments.

However, the command-line documentation explicitly states that you cannot provide both a database and a `subject` sequence:

```
-db <String>
BLAST database name
 * Incompatible with:  subject, subject_loc
-subject <File_In>
Subject sequence(s) to search
 * Incompatible with:  db, gilist, seqidlist, negative_gilist,
   db_soft_mask, db_hard_mask
```

How is the e-value calculated when using BLAST-2-Sequences on the command line? (I am fairly certain I do not have the nr database downloaded.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need the nr database for BLAST to calculate an E-value.
It will be calculated based on the alignment of n sequences.
The exact procedure is mathematically complex but if you want to read the original paper it is here:
http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC53667/pdf/pnas01031-0226.pdf

a simplified version you will find here:

http://homepages.ulb.ac.be/~dgonze/TEACHING/stat_scores.pdf

Comment: BLAST does need a database to calculate the E-value. A database should first be made out of the `n` sequences and then, as you said, BLAST will calculate E-value from that.

Comment: Well yes in the sense that you need sequences to look after but the database can be as numerous as one other sequence

Answer (score 2):

You should first understand what the meaning of E-value is. E-value is the likelihood of a random match having a certain score in given database. So, you are right that a database is required to calculate E-value. The online algorithm calculates it from not necessarily the `nr` database but **any** selected target database which could be RefSeq or organism specific databases (`nr` is the default).

When you are just aligning two sequences, E-value does not make any sense and there is no need to look at E-value at all. If you are aligning a sequence with a list of many sequences then you have to first make a database of your selected sequences using `makeblastdb`.

Now, when you do the alignment, E-value will be calculated from this database.